# How does the coded ui testing detect failure in the application?

Tags: c#-4.0, user-interface, visual-studio-2012, coded-ui-tests

I understand the general theory of how coded ui testing offered by visual studio 2012 ultimate works for an application. Like by means of UI action recorded from running an application or by existing test cases, we can assert or generate test codes. I would like to know the difference between unit testing and coded ui testing implementation in the developed codes.

Comment: Cded UI is just one of many test methods used to check the correct operation of a system. Coded UI focuses on the function of the system as seen by the user interface. Find a good book or tutorial on methods of testing.

Comment: can you suggest me name of a good tutorial?

Comment: I have edited my question. Im still not sure about the answer. I will be glad if any one enlighten me in the context.

Answer (score 3):

**Great Tip for coded UI Test's in vs2012**

**Go to -**   *C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE*

Find the file QTAgent32.exe.config

Open it in notepad++ or whatever and change the following code to below

```
<switches>
  <!-- You must use integral values for "value".
       Use 0 for off, 1 for error, 2 for warn, 3 for info, and 4 for verbose. -->
  <add name="EqtTraceLevel" value="4" />
</switches>
```

What it does is record every step of your test and takes screenshots and puts it into a nice html document. At the end of your Test click output scroll down and you'll see a html file.

After figuring this out I don't understand how you could possibly run coded UI test's without it.